# XMTV PlayerActivity launch

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

M developing and app in which i have to fire an Intent to play video in XMTV player app. I have tried following code but it only opening the app not going to player view.. So can anyone help in exact VideoPlayer class of XMTV

```
Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
        bnd.putString("path", uri);
        bnd.putString("name", "samplayer");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.xmtvplayer.watch.live.streams","org.zeipel.videoplayer.XMTVPlayer");
        intent.putExtras(bnd);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass link to video file or video stream as path parameter. 
bnd.putString("path", "http://exampla.com/live/video.m3u8");